# Rewrite Tool: rewrite url with parameters

Tags: url-rewrite

I have a url like:

`shop/artikel_solo.php?abc=1` that needs to become `myurlslug-of-the-article1.html`
`shop/artikel_solo.php?abc=2` that needs to become `myurlslug-of-the-article2.html`
and so on.

How to tell Magento to respect the query string while rewriting the url?

I also tried this solution: https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento-Redirect-Loses-URL-Querystring/td-p/4608 but I don't think it  is acutally the right one.

Comment: are u want for only this url ?

Comment: no. it is a  redirect management of an old shop. So I need abc=1-N. And event more. I need to use the magento rewrite tool, since it is  about 2k rewrites of article urls